composer vendor override - Cannot declare class because the name is already in use
I needed to modify some vendor files, which I did the following way (which was fine in the past):
I copy the vendor file to a vendor-override directory outside the vendor directory and modify it to my needs. Then modify composer.json by adding the original vendor file to "exclude-from-classmap" and add my file to "files"
example:
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/",
            "Routes\\Web\\": "routes/web/"
        },
        "exclude-from-classmap": [
            "vendor/area17/twill/src/Models/Model.php",
            "vendor/area17/twill/src/Models/Media.php"
        ],
        "files": [
            "vendor-override/twill/Model.php",
            "vendor-override/twill/Media.php"
        ]
    },

Now my problem is, that "vendor/area17/twill/src/Models/Media.php" inherits from "vendor/area17/twill/src/Models/Model.php"
If I run composer dump-auto, I get the following error:
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot declare class A17\Twill\Models\Model, because the name is already in use in C:\Database\SourceDB\modulbau-shop\vendor-override\twill\Model.php on line 23

I also tried deleting the vendor Model.php and Media.php file (for testing):
Then I get the following error instead:
In Media.php line 12:
                                            
  [Error]                                   
  Class "A17\Twill\Models\Model" not found  
                                            

Exception trace:
  at C:\Database\SourceDB\modulbau-shop\vendor-override\twill\Media.php:12
 require() at C:\Database\SourceDB\modulbau-shop\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php:41
 {closure}() at C:\Database\SourceDB\modulbau-shop\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php:45

To me it seems that vendor-override/twill/Media.php is still referencing to the file in vendor for some reason (perhaps because they were originally in the same folder?)
I tried adding an explicit import (use statement to the Media file, but it did not help. I still get the Class "A17\Twill\Models\Model" not found error)
vendor-override/twill/Media.php
<?php

namespace A17\Twill\Models;

use A17\Twill\Models\Model; // I added this line
use A17\Twill\Services\MediaLibrary\ImageService;
use App\Models\Subdomain;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class Media extends Model {
  ...

I don't really understand why it still tries to reference the vendor file, when I explicitly excluded that one from the classmap. Any ideas how to fix that?

This question is similar to: Redefine Class Methods or Class. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
